# Elasticsearch uses too much of server resources

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have elastisearch installed on my server size of the which is 10GB roughly, I have 16GB of RAM and 1TB of space. But still there are couple of strange issues that I am unable to understand about elasticsearch.

1. I have dedicated 10GB of ram to elasticsearch still my shards goes down and shows out of memory error when there is heavy insert operation happening.
2. Randomly elasticsearch stats using maximum resources of my server as shown shown below as a result server performance is almost dead

   [image: i9yuF]

Comment: What is the size of your index?

Comment: My total size of elasticsearch is approx 10GB in size, I have many index's but only one index has large number of entries i.e 1605835 and there index have very few entries

Comment: What is the perl process in the screenshot doing?

Comment: these are the elasticsearch  processes running on the server causing the high CPU usage